# Android: Where to find files written to internal storage?

Tags: android, file, debugging, directory, installation

I am new to android programming, and have been trying to write a file to internal storage, and believe I have succeeded.

HOWEVER I have probably written like 20 different variations of "Test File" to whatever directory I was writing too, and now I am trying to find that directory on my android device so I can delete those files.

I have searched through /system/app and cannot find my app there. Am I looking in the wrong place? or does something different happen when you deploy it through Android Studio debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files written to the internal storage are private to your app. Only the app can access the files. You can write delete functionality in your app or if you uninstall the app, those files will be deleted.

For [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal):

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Comment: I chose to just uninstall the app. I didn't remember all of the "Test File" "testFile" "fileName" "test_file" file names I used, so uninstalling was just easier. I realized I need them to be public anyways, so I will change that.

Answer (score 0):

Files for your app are stored in a subdirectory of `/data/data` and are only accessible to your app unless you have root privileges on the device.  If you want to delete the files, you will need to add "delete" functionality to your app, or root your device.  I suspect the former will probably be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but for anyone looking for files created in internal storage: you can view them in Device File Explorer in Android Studio. Just go to `data/data/your.package.name/files`.